# Concrete dampness in shed

Tags: concrete

A contractor built my shed on a new concrete slab in September 2021,he sealed the the bottom of shed yet the concrete floor continues to be damp. Will this create more problems in the long run? What can I do?

Comment: How was the bottom of the shed "sealed"?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in a garage at a previous house. It happens when there is no vapor barrier below the concrete. The garage was added in 2003, and the vapor barrier requirement didn't show up until 2005. Since the ground below the concrete is effectively always wet, without a barrier the water will always migrate the only direction it can: up through the concrete.

I ultimately mitigated it by improving the gutters to keep water away from the foundation, treating the concrete with a densifier to reduce the water migration through the surface and reduce spalling, and placing a ventilated floor tile system over the concrete. It didn't stop all the water getting in, but it meant that the little bit of water that did get in no longer caused trouble for anything I was storing on the floor. I also considered an epoxy system, though be aware that those are tough to properly apply so that they will stay on a wet surface, and you have to use one that is rated for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are sprays that can be applied from the top.  I have had success with **Aquron 2000**.  When I first obtained it, they had just started.  So they will let me have it if I request it.  But now, they will only sell it to registered applicators.

It is water-based silicon liquid.  It is sprayed with a higher pressure than normal spraying to force it into the pores.  It then solidifies and blocks water from passing through.  They have even better products, that I have not used because of the increased cost.  I am not associated with them.

[Acquron](https://aquron.com/products/aquron-2000-cure-and-seal/)